# Get ride of 0.0 location using google locationManager

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

I am using google location to get the location based on the best provider, so i am running that on a service, the service is responsable to update location based on a defined distance and time.

Everything is working well when i update my location, but i wanna get ride of the 0.0 location, when i doesn't update the location i need to get the current location, or to use the lastknowlocation how can i do it using my code below?

```
    public class MyService extends Service
    {
        private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
        private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
        private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
        private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

        private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
        private Intent intent;
        Context context;


        Location mLastLocation;

        public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            public MyService getServerInstance() {
                return MyService.this;
            }
        }

        public Location getLocation(){
            return mLastLocation;
        }


        private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
        {

            public LocationListener(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
                mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
                mLastLocation.set(location);
            }


            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
            }
        }

        LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
                new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
        };


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            context = getApplicationContext();
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return START_STICKY;
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
            initializeLocationManager();
            try {
               //mLastLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[1]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                //mLastLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                        mLocationListeners[0]);
            } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
            super.onDestroy();
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void initializeLocationManager() {
            Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (mLocationManager == null) {
                mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }
        }


**main activity call of the service**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        askPermission();
    }


    public void nextAct(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,GpsGetCoordinates.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public static final int REQ_PERMISSION = 99;


    private boolean checkPermission() {
        // PEDE PERMISSÃO SE A MESMA AINDA NÃO TIVER SIDO CONCEDIDA
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
    }

    // PEDIDO DE PERMISSÃO
    private void askPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                REQ_PERMISSION);
    }

    // VERIFICAÇÃO DA RESPOSTA DO UTILIZADOR AO PEDIDO DE PERMISSÃO
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull
            String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
        switch ( requestCode ) {
            case REQ_PERMISSION: {
                if ( grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                    Log.d("PERMISSAO","DADA");
                    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
                } else {
                    // PERMISSÃO NEGADA
                    Log.w("fail", "permissionsDenied()");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get a location that is !=0.0, store it in a variable, or in Shared Preferences, or anywhere else you want. Then the next time you get 0.0 from locationManager, just use the latest real value that you stored previously.